# How do I use imageWithContentsOfFile for an array of images used in an animation?

Tags: ios, uiimage

This is what I currently have:

```
NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:21];

 for(int count = 1; count <= 21; count++)
{
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"dance2_%03d.jpg", count];
    UIImage  *frame    = [UIImage imageNamed:fileName];
    [images addObject:frame];
}
```

UIImage imageNamed is causing me some memory issues and I would like to switch to imageWithContentsOfFile.

I can make it work with a single image, but not the whole array:

```
NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:21];

for(int count = 1; count <= 21; count++)
{
    NSString *fileName = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingString:@"/dance2_001.jpg"];
    UIImage  *frame    = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fileName];
    [images addObject:frame];
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 21; i++)
    {
        [images addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"dance2_%03d", i] ofType:@"jpg"]]];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

what you should do first is create an array with the images for your animation like something like this:

```
NSMutableArray* images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                             [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image1" ofType:@"jpg"]],
                             [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image2" ofType:@"jpg"]],
                             nil];
```

then you can add it to an UIImageView to animate it like this:

```
UIImageView* animationImagesView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(posX, posY, frameWidth, frameHeight)]; 
animationImagesView.animationImages = images; //array of images to be animate
animationImagesView.animationDuration = 1.0; //duration of animation
animationImagesView.animationRepeatCount = 1; //number of time to repeat animation
[self.view addSubview:animationImagesView];
```

now you can start and stop the animation using these two calls:

```
[animationImagesView startAnimating]; //starts animation 
[animationImagesView stopAnimating]; //stops animation
```

hope this helps. also remember to release and nil your Array and UIImageView when done.