# Adding UIImage to NSMutable array for an animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, memory-leaks, uiimage

I have an app that creates an animation from images stored in a group in my project navigator (not `Images.xcassets`). This code "works" in that it animates properly, but using `imageNamed` causes a memory leak because the image files are not getting deallocated.

I can't figure out why adding with `imageNamed:` works adds images to my array, but `imageWithContentsOfFile:` doesn't.

A little info on the mechanics of my app:

`self.myPhoto` is set on the segue from another `ViewController`. The number of images can vary, so I test to see the file is "there" before adding it to the array.

Filenames follow this naming convention:

```
"1-1.jpg"
"2-1.jpg"
"2-2.jpg"
"99-1.jpg"
"99-2.jpg"
"99-3.jpg"
"99-4.jpg"
```

This code works, but the images don't deallocate, causing a memory leak:

```
- (void)startAnimation {

    NSMutableArray *imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int imageNumber = 1; self.myPhoto != nil; imageNumber++) {
        NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%d.jpg", self.myPhoto, imageNumber];

        // check if a file exists
        if ([UIImage imageNamed:fileName]) {
            // if it exists, add it to the array
            [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:fileName]];
        } else {
            // otherwise, don't add image to the array
            break;
        }
    }

    self.myImageView.animationImages = imageArray;
    self.myImageView.animationDuration = 1.5f;
    self.myImageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
    self.myImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [self.myImageView startAnimating];

}
```

I ran Instruments on it and saw I had a memory leak emanating from my animation. Digging around a little on StackOverflow, I discovered the manner I'm adding my files to `myArray` results in images not getting deallocated.

So I tried this, instead:

```
- (void)startAnimation {

    NSMutableArray *imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int imageNumber = 1; self.myPhoto != nil; imageNumber++) {
        NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%d", self.myPhoto, imageNumber];

        // check if a file exists
        if ([UIImage imageNamed:fileName]) {
            // if it exists, add it to the array
            [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", fileName] ofType:@"jpg"]]];
            NSLog(@"%@ added to imageArray", fileName);
        } else {
            // otherwise, don't add image to the array
            break;
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"There are %lu images in imageArray", (unsigned long)imageArray.count);

    self.myImageView.animationImages = imageArray;
    self.myImageView.animationDuration = 1.5f;
    self.myImageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
    self.myImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [self.myImageView startAnimating];

}
```

When I do it this way, the page where the animation loads appears, but the images don't get added to my array--the . This is a well-documented issue. Here are a few posts covering this problem:

[Dirty Memory because of CoreAnimation and CG image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563348/dirty-memory-because-of-coreanimation-and-cg-image)

[How do I use imageWithContentsOfFile for an array of images used in an animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886959/how-do-i-use-imagewithcontentsoffile-for-an-array-of-images-used-in-an-animation)

Thank you for reading. I'm stumped, though I'm confident the resolution to this problem is a startlingly stupid oversight on my part. Prove me right ;)

Comment: I think it might just be that your path needs to have [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] at the beginning? Edit: Ah, nevermind, mislead by the name of your variable :P

Comment: Silly question, but you are using ARC, right? Both the questions you linked are pre ARC

Comment: I think I'm using ARC. I'm running Xcode 6.4, deployment target 8.1 (tried 8.4 for S's and G's when I ran out of ideas)

Comment: For the second method, do you get the right amount of photos? Or is the array just empty? If it's empty, try logging each image and see if it exists or not. It might be that you're using the wrong resource path

Comment: I got it! Posting an answer here. It works, I don't know why this works, but the "correct" way doesn't get the job done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some minor changes out of desperation and I stumbled into the "answer". Comments note where I made changes:

```
- (void)startAnimation {

    NSMutableArray *imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int imageNumber = 1; self.myPhoto != nil; imageNumber++) {
        // I set the filename here, adding .jpg to it
        NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%d.jpg", self.myPhoto, imageNumber];

        // check if a file exists
        if ([UIImage imageNamed:fileName]) {
            // if it exists, add it to the array
            // I blanked out ofType, as it's set when I create the local fileName variable
            [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", fileName] ofType:@""]]];
        } else {
            // otherwise, don't add image to the array
            break;
        }
    }

    self.myImageView.animationImages = imageArray;
    self.myImageView.animationDuration = 1.5f;
    self.myImageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
    self.myImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [self.myImageView startAnimating];

}
```

Comment: Weird how just adding the .jpg to the end of the filename made it work

Comment: I tried it with and without when I created the local `fileName` variable, then I tried it in `addObject` and stumbled into it. Thank you for your thoughts and for reading.